# having issues with my site positioning <div>'s

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner and not a developer by trait but do have some experience and I'm trying to learn, so any help will be greatly appreciated. Here are the issues that I'm trying to fix.

1. Some of my containers class="section", seem to have margins either on the top or bottom. All of the sections are supposed to be flushed together and can't figure out why the first 2 have these white margins but the last one doesn't.
2. the last "section" at the bottom, doesn't want to float: left; it's very stubborn.

Here is my code and CSS:

https://fortuneinternational.box.com/s/u5su860o7a6ovbytzk5407p8lg8rs7jr

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net) would be easier to help

Comment: not sure what that means, im sorry.

Comment: Post your code in your question! No one feels like going through your box, that sounds weird

Comment: That means SO requires enough code inside your question to see the issue and better complement with entire code on tools like codepen - plunker - jsfiddle search about those. Nobody will download your code and debug that isn't how it works

Comment: Ok my apologies. Here is the fiddle. Not sure if i set this up right, but hopefully i did.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ismy31/aymgokL2/#&togetherjs=6R5vMvV6FP

Comment: funny how everyone was very fast to comment when criticizing me on how i uploaded my code, yet no one actually helps. =/

Answer (score 0):

On your css file, replace this

```
.girl_boat {
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}
```

with this

```
.girl_boat {
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
}
```

**EDIT**
You are assigning a fixed height for the divs and expecting the images to follow. Set the heights of the the images to the same height of color_green, purple ... This should "glue" everything together.

```
.girl_boat {
    width: 50%;
    height:258px;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
}
.view_image {
    width: 50%;
    height:258px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: updated jsfiddle here. that sort of helped but still has some margin issues

Comment: What kind of margin issues?

Comment: Screen shot here:
https://fortuneinternational.box.com/s/wt6k7notojc8rsvmfwsv1r8ywc3mqkt4

everything is supposed to be flushed together. For some reason the green box is messing everything up.

Comment: Check my edited answer. That should solve your issue.

Comment: Glad it helped. Good luck !
You can mark it as answered then !